# Violación de una restricción de Integridad Referencial al usar Hibernate

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Veran, tengo un programa en el cual tengo 2 tablas.
Una es Seguro, que almacena los datos de una persona.
La otra es AsistenciaMedica, la cual almacena las incidencias medicas que sufre una persona.
Una asistencia medica se asigna a un solo seguro, pero cada seguro puede tener en su haber varias asistencias medicas.

Variables del Seguro:

```
package es.makigas.hibernate.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

public class Seguro implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int id;

String nif;

String nombre;

String ape1;

String ape2;

int edad;

int numHijos;

LocalDate fechaCreacion;

List<AsistenciaMedica> asistenciasmedicas;

public Seguro() {}

public Seguro(int id, String nif, String nombre, String ape1, String ape2, int edad, int numHijos, LocalDate fechaCreacion){
    this.id = id;
    this.nif = nif;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ape1 = ape1;
    this.ape2 = ape2;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.numHijos = numHijos;
    this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNif() {
    return nif;
}

public void setNif(String nif) {
    this.nif = nif;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApe1() {
    return ape1;
}

public void setApe1(String ape1) {
    this.ape1 = ape1;
}

public String getApe2() {
    return ape2;
}

public void setApe2(String ape2) {
    this.ape2 = ape2;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public int getNumHijos() {
    return numHijos;
}

public void setNumHijos(int numHijos) {
    this.numHijos = numHijos;
}

public LocalDate getFechaCreacion() {
    return fechaCreacion;
}

public void setFechaCreacion(LocalDate fechaCreacion) {
    this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
}

public List<AsistenciaMedica> getAsistenciasmedicas() {
    return asistenciasmedicas;
}

public void setAsistenciasmedicas(List<AsistenciaMedica> asistenciasmedicas) {
    this.asistenciasmedicas = asistenciasmedicas;
}
}
```

La tabla de AsistenciaMedica:

```
package es.makigas.hibernate.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AsistenciaMedica implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int idAsistenciaMedica;

    Seguro seguro;

    String breveDescripcion;

    String lugar;

    int Idx;

    public AsistenciaMedica(){}

    public AsistenciaMedica(int idAsistenciaMedica, Seguro seguro, String breveDescripcion, String lugar){
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
        this.seguro=seguro;
        this.breveDescripcion = breveDescripcion;
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }

    public int getIdAsistenciaMedica() {
        return idAsistenciaMedica;
    }

    public void setIdAsistenciaMedica(int idAsistenciaMedica) {
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
    }

    public Seguro getSeguro() {
        return seguro;
    }

    public void setSeguro(Seguro seguro) {
        this.seguro = seguro;
    }

    public String getBreveDescripcion() {
        return breveDescripcion;
    }

    public void setBreveDescripcion(String breveDescripcion) {
        this.breveDescripcion = breveDescripcion;
    }

    public String getLugar() {
        return lugar;
    }

    public void setLugar(String lugar) {
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }   
}
```

Para probar el programa, utilizo este código almacenado en un paquete Test:

```
package tests;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica;
import es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro;

public class TestSeguros{
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistencia");
    private static EntityManager manager=emf.createEntityManager();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Seguro seguro = new Seguro(321, "12345678Z", "Carlos", "Perez", "Olmo", 54, 1, LocalDate.of(2015,8,12));
        AsistenciaMedica asistenciaMedica1=new AsistenciaMedica(321, seguro, "médico de cabecera", "Mislata");
        AsistenciaMedica asistenciaMedica2=new AsistenciaMedica(322, seguro, "Operación de bypass", "Sevilla");

        manager.getTransaction().begin();

        manager.persist(seguro);

        manager.persist(asistenciaMedica1);
        manager.persist(asistenciaMedica2);

        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<AsistenciaMedica> a=(List<AsistenciaMedica>) manager.createQuery("FROM AsistenciaMedica").getResultList();
        System.out.println("Incidencias: "+a.size());
        for(AsistenciaMedica as:a){
            System.out.println("Incidencia: "+as.getBreveDescripcion());
        }
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Esto que quiero hacer lo logre en el pasado utilizando JPA, pero en esta ocasión debo utilizar los ficheros hbm.xml
Para eso, cree por un lado AsistenciaMedica.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica" table="AsistenciaMedica" >
        <id column="idAsistenciaMedica" name="idAsistenciaMedica" type="integer"/>
        <property name="breveDescripcion" />
        <property name="lugar" />

        <many-to-one name="seguro">
            <column name="id"  />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Y por otro lado Seguro.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro" table="Seguro" >
        <id column="Id" name="id" type="integer"/>
        <property name="nif" />
        <property name="nombre" />
        <property name="ape1" />
        <property name="ape2" />
        <property name="edad" />
        <property name="numHijos" />
        <property name="fechaCreacion" />

        <list name="asistenciasmedicas"  cascade="all" inverse="false"  >
            <key>
                <column name="idAsistenciaMedica"  />
            </key>
                <list-index>
                    <column name="Idx"  />
                </list-index>
            <one-to-many class="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me topo con este mensaje de error:

```
Violación de una restricción de Integridad Referencial: "FKDVN9D4IPYG2WXHRA4HP4N0UM1: PUBLIC.ASISTENCIAMEDICA FOREIGN KEY(IDASISTENCIAMEDICA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SEGURO(ID) (322)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKDVN9D4IPYG2WXHRA4HP4N0UM1: PUBLIC.ASISTENCIAMEDICA FOREIGN KEY(IDASISTENCIAMEDICA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SEGURO(ID) (322)"; SQL statement:
insert into AsistenciaMedica (breveDescripcion, lugar, id, idAsistenciaMedica) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-196]
```

Presiento que el error esta en la variable Idx que se ve en AsistenciaMedica.java y que se menciona en Seguro.hbm.xml, pues en la documentación que sigo no esta muy claro de donde sale.

Edito: He probado a poner antes del commit este código:

```
System.out.println(asistenciaMedica2.getSeguro().getNif());
```

Y se muestra su valor antes de que salga la excepción. Diria que el error se produce al relacionar las variables dentro de la tabla sin afectar a las clases en si.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que de acuerdo al mensaje de error obtenido tenes que el id de asistencia medica que esta apuntando al id de seguro.

Violación de una restricción de Integridad Referencial: "FKDVN9D4IPYG2WXHRA4HP4N0UM1: 
PUBLIC.ASISTENCIAMEDICA FOREIGN KEY(IDASISTENCIAMEDICA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SEGURO(ID)

Lo que hice fue replicar tu ejercicio usando hibernate puro generando todo desde Eclipse y funciona OK. A continuación menciono lo que use.

En la base de datos utilice MySql y tengo el siguiente modelo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde la clave foránea en la tabla AsistenciaMedica esta apuntando a la clave primaria de la tabla Seguros. A la clave foránea la llame seguro_id

Script de base de datos. En mi caso use MySql

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ejemplo2
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ejemplo2
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ejemplo2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `ejemplo2` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ejemplo2`.`seguro`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ejemplo2`.`seguro` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nif` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ape1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ape2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `edad` INT NULL,
  `numhijos` INT NULL,
  `fechaCreacion` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ejemplo2`.`AsistenciaMedica`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ejemplo2`.`AsistenciaMedica` (
  `idAsistenciaMedica` INT NOT NULL,
  `breveDescripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lugar` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `seguro_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAsistenciaMedica`),
  INDEX `fk_AsistenciaMedica_seguro_idx` (`seguro_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AsistenciaMedica_seguro`
    FOREIGN KEY (`seguro_id`)
    REFERENCES `ejemplo2`.`seguro` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Archivos proyecto java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego respecto a los archivos generados tenemos lo siguiente:

Seguro.java

```
package tablas;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
/**
 * Seguro generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="seguro")
public class Seguro implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    private String nif;
    private String nombre;
    private String ape1;
    private String ape2;
    private Integer edad;
    private Integer numhijos;
    private Date fechaCreacion;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="seguro")   
    private Set<Asistenciamedica> asistenciamedicas = new HashSet(0);

    public Seguro() {
    }

    public Seguro(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Seguro(int id, String nif, String nombre, String ape1, String ape2, Integer edad, Integer numhijos,
            Date fechaCreacion, Set<Asistenciamedica> asistenciamedicas) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ape1 = ape1;
        this.ape2 = ape2;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.numhijos = numhijos;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
        this.asistenciamedicas = asistenciamedicas;
    }

    public Seguro(int id, String nif, String nombre, String ape1, String ape2, Integer edad, Integer numhijos,
            Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ape1 = ape1;
        this.ape2 = ape2;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.numhijos = numhijos;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNif() {
        return this.nif;
    }

    public void setNif(String nif) {
        this.nif = nif;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApe1() {
        return this.ape1;
    }

    public void setApe1(String ape1) {
        this.ape1 = ape1;
    }

    public String getApe2() {
        return this.ape2;
    }

    public void setApe2(String ape2) {
        this.ape2 = ape2;
    }

    public Integer getEdad() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(Integer edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Integer getNumhijos() {
        return this.numhijos;
    }

    public void setNumhijos(Integer numhijos) {
        this.numhijos = numhijos;
    }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return this.fechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }


    public Set<Asistenciamedica> getAsistenciamedicas() {
        return this.asistenciamedicas;
    }

    public void setAsistenciamedicas(Set<Asistenciamedica> asistenciamedicas) {
        this.asistenciamedicas = asistenciamedicas;
    }

}
```

Asistenciamedica.java

```
package tablas;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Asistenciamedica generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="AsistenciaMedica")
public class Asistenciamedica implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="idAsistenciaMedica")
    private int idAsistenciaMedica;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="seguro_id", nullable=false)
    private Seguro seguro;
    private String breveDescripcion;
    private String lugar;

    public Asistenciamedica() {
    }

    public Asistenciamedica(int idAsistenciaMedica, Seguro seguro) {
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
        this.seguro = seguro;
    }

    public Asistenciamedica(int idAsistenciaMedica, Seguro seguro, String breveDescripcion, String lugar) {
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
        this.seguro = seguro;
        this.breveDescripcion = breveDescripcion;
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }

    public int getIdAsistenciaMedica() {
        return this.idAsistenciaMedica;
    }

    public void setIdAsistenciaMedica(int idAsistenciaMedica) {
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
    }

    public Seguro getSeguro() {
        return this.seguro;
    }

    public void setSeguro(Seguro seguro) {
        this.seguro = seguro;
    }

    public String getBreveDescripcion() {
        return this.breveDescripcion;
    }

    public void setBreveDescripcion(String breveDescripcion) {
        this.breveDescripcion = breveDescripcion;
    }

    public String getLugar() {
        return this.lugar;
    }

    public void setLugar(String lugar) {
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }

}
```

Luego siguen los hbm.xml:

Seguro.hbm.xml- fijate que yo use un Set en vez de un list para el mapeo y el para el column name se usa seguro_id (parte final del archivo donde también esta la relación uno a muchos), lo cual difiere de tu versión, que vos usas el id de asistencias medicas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true" default-access="property" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
    <class catalog="ejemplo2" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="tablas.Seguro" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="seguro">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="nif" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="nif"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="nombre" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="nombre"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="ape1" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="ape1"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="ape2" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="ape2"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="edad" optimistic-lock="true" type="java.lang.Integer" unique="false">
            <column name="edad"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="numhijos" optimistic-lock="true" type="java.lang.Integer" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="numhijos"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="fechaCreacion" optimistic-lock="true" type="timestamp" unique="false">
            <column length="19" name="fechaCreacion"/>
        </property>
        <set embed-xml="true" fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" mutable="true" name="asistenciamedicas" optimistic-lock="true" sort="unsorted" table="asistenciamedica">
            <key on-delete="noaction">
                <column name="seguro_id" not-null="true"/>
            </key>            
            <one-to-many class="tablas.Asistenciamedica" embed-xml="true" not-found="exception"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Asistenciamedica.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true" default-access="property" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
    <class catalog="ejemplo2" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="tablas.Asistenciamedica" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="asistenciamedica">
        <id name="idAsistenciaMedica" type="int">
            <column name="idAsistenciaMedica"/>
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one class="tablas.Seguro" embed-xml="true" fetch="select" insert="true" name="seguro" not-found="exception" optimistic-lock="true" unique="false" update="true">
            <column name="seguro_id" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="breveDescripcion" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="breveDescripcion"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="lugar" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
            <column length="45" name="lugar"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Archivos hibernate de configuración:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">supermax03</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejemplo2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show.sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="tablas.Seguro" package="tablas" resource="/tablas.Seguro.hbm.xml"></mapping>
        <mapping class="tablas.Asistenciamedica" package="tablas" resource="/tablas.Asistenciamedica.hbm.xml"></mapping>  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.revenge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-catalog="ejemplo2" match-name="asistenciamedica"/>
  <table-filter match-catalog="ejemplo2" match-name="seguro"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

HibernateUtils.java necesario para crear la sesion desde el llamador

```
package utils;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtils {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    static {
        sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
         }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Finalmente el programa llamador.

```
package programa;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import tablas.Asistenciamedica;
import tablas.Seguro;
import utils.HibernateUtils;

public class Prueba {

    private static Session session; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        session=HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        Date fecha=new Date();
        Seguro seguro=new Seguro(350,"12345678Z", "Carlos", "Perez", "Olmo", 54, 1,fecha);
        Asistenciamedica asistenciaMedica1=new Asistenciamedica(350, seguro, "médico de cabecera", "Mislata");
        Asistenciamedica asistenciaMedica2=new Asistenciamedica(351, seguro, "Operación de bypass", "Sevilla");

        session.save(seguro);
        session.save(asistenciaMedica1);
        session.save(asistenciaMedica2);
        tx.commit();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Asistenciamedica> a=(List<Asistenciamedica>) session.createQuery("FROM Asistenciamedica").getResultList();

        for(Asistenciamedica as:a){
               System.out.println("Incidencia: "+as.getBreveDescripcion());
            }       

        session.close();

    }

}
```

y la salida por pantalla de ejecución exitosa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Base de datos todo OK también

```
select * from seguro;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT *
FROM asistenciamedica;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontré un video un ilustrativo acerca de como crear estos archivos de mapeo de  de forma automática  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ssa2-D9W_E

Espero sea de tu utilidad.